# If $F(n)$ is the unique number of arranging $n \ge 1$ unique items, prove inductively that $F(n) = n!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-writing, factorial, infinite-product

This question doesn't seem so hard. Then again it does. I'm struggling to move past the induction hypothesis.

The base case is obviously $1!$.

Assuming that $F(n) = n!$ , I take the $(n+1)!$ elements. This is where I'm lost because I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What is the $(n + 1)!$ element? What does that even mean? You probably want to start with $F(n) = n!$, and flesh out what that means. It means you have all of these ways to arrange the n items. Now where do you put the next item?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Well I feel like if we have to arrange 4 items, thats $4!$, right? For an additional item, that would be $(4 + 1)!$, correct? That's just the way we were thought to handle induction, by adding an extra element.

Comment: Yes, but all you have demonstrated is that you know $4 + 1 = 5$ (!) The reasoning should be something along the lines of "We have these 4! arrangements, and to add a fifth item, we can place it *before* any of the 4 items, or after the last one..."

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 How exactly should I approach that with an inductive approach?

Comment: $(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n! = (n+1)F(n!)= F(n+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have to arrange $n+1$ items and you know that you have $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ items.

Pick an item. You have $n+1$ choices for the placement of the item you chose. For each of this you're left to arrange the remaining $n$ items which can be done in $n!$ ways.

Thus the grand total is $n!+\cdots+n!$, $n+1$ times, i.e. $(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$